# Session transfer between asp.net and asp works in soome cases and in some cases not

Tags: asp.net, session, asp-classic, transfer

I transfer session from asp.net to classic asp.

I use MSSQL DB for it.

I have

SomeWebPage.aspx - this page is asp.net which save sesion, after it, it call by redirect

SessionTransfer.aspx -this page save sessions to DB and call by redirect

SessionTransfer.asp - this page load session from DB and cal by redirect

SomeWebPage.asp - this page doesn't need now about other pages, it just use session.

Problem is, that it works only if SomeWebPage.aspx, SessionTransfer.aspx, SessionTransfer.asp and SomeWebPage.asp are in same folder, or in same "web pages" folder on iis.

How can i do it if SomeWebPage.asp will be in other web folder. On same IIS server, but it will be specific web?

I use IIS 5.1 for developing and finished program will run on IIS 6.0.

Comment: If the session is saved and retrieved from DB, it would not matter where those pages are. There must be something else going on. Check that you don't have On Error Resume Next anywhere. What happens when the pages are in different folders? Have you checked the DB if the session values are being saved?

Comment: Problem is not in DB, SessionTransfer.asp read it OK in all cases, I debug it. Session is lost between SessionTransfer.asp and SomeWebPage.asp. Again. If SomeWebPage.asp is in same folder like other, it works. If it is in another folder, it Sessions saved by SessionTransfer.asp are lost. I thing it is problem that there are another "webs".

Comment: What do you mean by "webs"? Is is different site in IIS or different application in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that it was different applications.

SessionTransfer.asp must be it same application like SomeWebPage.asp (it wasn't)

and

SessionTransfer.aspx must be it same application (pool) like SomeWebPage.aspx (it was)

It ws teddy-bear problem. When we start discus about this, i realized where is problem :-D

thanks amit_g